# Creating a const share_ptr<pure_virtual_class> member

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, shared-ptr, member

I have a number of classes that derive from a pure virtal base:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

class derived_0 : public base {
public:
    int f() {return 0;}
};

class derived_1 : public base {
public:
    int f() {return 1;}
};
```

I only put two derived classes for brevity, but in practice I have more.

And I would like to create a class that has a const shared pointer to the base. I would like do to the following but I can't as I must initialize the const pointer in the initialization list:

```
class C{
public:
    C(bool type) { 
        if(type) {
            derived_0* xx = new derived_0;
            x = shared_ptr<base>( xx );
        }
        else {
            derived_1* xx = new derived1;
            x = shared_ptr<base>( xx );
        }
    } 
private:
    const share_ptr<base> x;
};
```

How can I get this functionality?

Comment: You forgot to mark `base::f()` as `virtual`

Comment: I wonder what exactly are error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You encapsulate the creation of the object in a function, like this:

```
shared_ptr<base> create_base(bool type) {
     if(type) {
         return make_shared<derived_0>();
     }
     else {
         return make_shared<derived_1>();
     }
}
```

And then you can use it in your initialization-list:

```
class C{
public:
    C(bool type)
    : x(create_base(type))
    {}
private:
    const share_ptr<base> x;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In simple cases like this precise example:

```
class C
{
    shared_ptr<Base> const x;
public:
    C( bool type ) 
        : x( type
            ? static_cast<Base*>( new Derived_0 )
            : static_cast<Base*>( new Derived_1 ) )
    {
    }
};
```

(And yes, the `static_cast`, or at least one of them, are necessary.)

In more general cases, where the decision logic is more complex, you
might want to create a static function which returns the `shared_ptr`,
e.g.:

```
class C
{
    shared_ptr<Base> const x;
    static shared_ptr<Base> makeSharedPtr( bool type );
public:
    C( bool type )
        : x( makeSharedPtr( type ) )
    {
    }
};
```

This will allow any imaginable logic (and a more complex set of
parameters as well).

Comment: Note that in your first case with the ternary operator, using `static_cast` like that means the destructor has to be virtual. If you instead create a temporary `shared_ptr` the pointer itself can save the exact derived class to delete later.

Comment: @MarkB But in general, if a class is polymorphic, you want the destructor to be virtual.